# Failed to run composer install on designed three organization from start using Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I'm setting up Hyperledger Composer Blockchain for my undergraduate thesis by designing 3 Organisation from start (I need 3 org from start so it's kind of awkward to deploy 2 and then join one more like the example from Fabric and Composer. I actually want to deploy in fabric but I think I don't have the time for that (I will do it for my master thesis)

I've tried the tutorial before (create 2 org then join one more) and I can run composer network start successfully, but when I ran it on my running 3 organisation, it got error

I'm not sure if I should show all my code here, so maybe I'll show my org 3 from all yaml file that should be the source of the error

(showing my added code)

docker-compose-cas.yaml

```
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org3
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/8d560caca38e3757c9704e68a53b2a3b00027ee0f940a5fd5f20051182c255a6_sk
    ports:
      - "9054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/8d560caca38e3757c9704e68a53b2a3b00027ee0f940a5fd5f20051182c255a6_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./org3-artifacts/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg3
    networks:
      - byfn
```

docker-compose-cli.yaml

```
peer0.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

docker-compose-cli.yaml

```
couchdb4:
    container_name: couchdb4
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "9984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org3.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb4:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb4

  couchdb5:
    container_name: couchdb5
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "10984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org3.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb5:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb5
```

docker-compose-e2e.yaml

```
volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:
  peer0.org3.example.com:
  peer1.org3.example.com:

....

  ca2:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org3
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/2e2efd3ddc1ac66712feb13c1747b217ffc2c4fef9dc701c224e084d09c3ba0e_sk
    ports:
      - "9054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/2e2efd3ddc1ac66712feb13c1747b217ffc2c4fef9dc701c224e084d09c3ba0e_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg3
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

crypto-config.yaml

```
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org3
    Domain: org3.example.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

endorsement-policy.json

```
"policy": {
        "3-of": [
            {
                "signed-by": 0
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 1
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 2
            }
        ]
    }
```

configtx.yaml

```
Profiles:

    ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    ThreeOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Alway got error like this when I run:

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n trade-network -V 0.2.6-deploy.0 -o endorsementPolicyFile=/tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A warehouse -C ./users/warehouse/admin-pub.pem -A asp -C ./users/asp/admin-pub.pem -A site -C ./users/site/admin-pub.pem
```

it showed up error like this (error at step seventeen in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org):

```
Starting business network trade-network at version 0.2.6-deploy.0

Processing these Network Admins: 
        userName: warehouse
        userName: asp
        userName: site

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been connected to receive the commit event
Command failed
```

I'm not really understand fabric that much, so it is because of the peer from org3 doesn't connected properly? or because of my policy?

Comment: You only showed the yaml file for org3-ca. What about definitions of org3-peers? Also did you generate certificates for org3 entities from cryptogen?

Comment: yeah I did. I can install my composer on org3 (so the ca is fine because whenever the ca is broken I always failed to install it) but I can't seem too start the network. for other file wait a minute, I'll edit it